# RDkit removes explicit Hydrogens while optimizing geometry

Tags: python, rdkit

I'm trying to optimize a bunch of molecules from an SDF file using `AllChem.MMFFOptimizeMolecule`. My molecules already have explicit hydrogens, but the warning told me:

```
Molecule does not have explicit Hs. Consider calling AddHs()
```

So I decided that it won't hurt to add the `AddHs()` command just in case. But even after adding that, the warning persists. Not only that, but when I write out the optimized molecules to a new SDF file, the hydrogens are missing.

So it seems that RDKit is removing my explicit hydrogens when reading in the SDF file using `Chem.SDMolSupplier(path)`, not adding hydrogens when I call `Chem.AddHs(mol)`, doing the optimization without them and then writing the opt geometries without hydrogens to the new file and I do not understand what I did to deserve this...

Here is my code:

```py
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem



def opt_sdf_coords(path='all_moles.sdf',outpath='all_moles_opt.sdf'):

    suppl = Chem.SDMolSupplier(path)
    w = Chem.SDWriter(outpath)

    for mol in suppl:
        Chem.AddHs(mol)
        AllChem.MMFFOptimizeMolecule(mol)

        w.write(mol)

    w.close()
```

This is an excerpt from the SDF file so that you can run the code yourself:

```
 OpenBabel06232316383D

  9  9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
    0.9772    0.0715   -0.0147 Br  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8573    0.0846   -0.0063 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6483    1.2076   -0.0051 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.9310    0.7321    0.0017 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.8622   -0.6331    0.0043 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6184   -1.0534   -0.0005 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.4204    2.2636   -0.0083 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7787    1.2827    0.0044 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7442   -1.2604    0.0095 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
  2  3  2  0  0  0  0
  2  6  1  0  0  0  0
  3  4  1  0  0  0  0
  3  7  1  0  0  0  0
  4  5  1  0  0  0  0
  4  8  1  0  0  0  0
  5  6  2  0  0  0  0
  5  9  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
$$$$

 OpenBabel06232316383D

  9  9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
    0.9772    0.0715   -0.0147 Br  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8573    0.0846   -0.0063 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6483    1.2076   -0.0051 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.9310    0.7321    0.0017 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.8622   -0.6331    0.0043 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6184   -1.0534   -0.0005 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.4204    2.2636   -0.0083 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7787    1.2827    0.0044 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7442   -1.2604    0.0095 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
  2  3  2  0  0  0  0
  2  6  1  0  0  0  0
  3  4  1  0  0  0  0
  3  7  1  0  0  0  0
  4  5  1  0  0  0  0
  4  8  1  0  0  0  0
  5  6  2  0  0  0  0
  5  9  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
$$$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDKit removes Hs when reading SDF files. That's why it calls for `AddHs`.

There is no need to `AddHs`. Just set `removeHs=False`.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem

def opt_sdf_coords(path='all_moles.sdf',outpath='all_moles_opt.sdf'):

    suppl = Chem.SDMolSupplier(path, removeHs=False)
    w = Chem.SDWriter(outpath)

    for mol in suppl:
        AllChem.MMFFOptimizeMolecule(mol)

        w.write(mol)

    w.close()
```

Comment: good to know. I just found a different docs page that I didn't find before that looks completely different to the one I know: https://www.rdkit.org/docs/cppapi/classRDKit_1_1SDMolSupplier.html
is this new? Also, why did the `AddHs()` command not work? Even if `SDMolSupplier()` removes Hs by default, why didn't the mols get Hs when I explicitly used the command to add them? Also, did I do something wrong to deserve that downvote?

Comment: @J.Doe You need a new mol object. When using `mol = Chem.AddHs(mol)` it works for me. The downvote was not from me.